# How to re-add a container in Bluemix

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

When I try to add a container to space A in bluemix I receive the following error:

> BXNUI0521E: While attempting to create a container from the image, an
>   internal error with incident ID 747-1463152155.505-13996376 occurred.
>   Some resources, such as an IP address or memory, were not available
>   when the namespace was being retrieved.

Also when I run `cf ic login` in space A I receive:

```
{
    "code": "IC5005E", 
    "description": "The maximum quota for this organization is 2 floating IPs and 2048 memory. The action you are trying to complete, such as logging into a new space, would exceed the maximum quota. The current floating IP usage is 2 and this action would require an additional 2. The current memory usage is 2048 and this action would require an additional 2048. Reduce usage for the organization or ask your organization manager to adjust the quota allocation in the Manage Organizations page.", 
    "incident_id": "744-1463151704.272-14000754", 
    "name": "IPAndMemoryQuotaExceeded", 
    "rc": "500", 
    "type": "Quota"
}
```

I believe this is because I created a container in space B, which assigned two IP addresses to it. I have since deleted this space. How do I reduce the floating IP usage down to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this quota (2 IP addresses and 2048 MB) I am assuming you have a Bluemix free account.

In this case you can only create containers in one single space within your organization. Once you created containers in `space B` you cannot create any containers in `space A` (even if you have enough quota for that).

You mentioned you deleted `space B` (where you originally created containers), so you will have wait a while (usually within 24 hours or less) so your account is reset.

After that you will be able to login again to a new space, create a new namespace and start using containers again.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would need the following steps:

At first you need to target the right org and space using:

```
cf target -o ORG -s SPACE
```

You can list all allocated public IP addresses (available or not) using:

```
cf ic ip list -a
```

Then you can release an IP using:

```
cf ic ip release [IPAddr]
```

However in your case you may not be able to release the IPs if they are bound to a deleted space. If the above steps don't fix the issue you may open a support request asking the IBM Containers team to release the IPs.